# How to write JMH benchmarks in Kotlin without using melix/jmh-gradle-plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jmh

Kotlin benchmarks using [plugin](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin) are written and run. As far as I understand, `jmh` is focused on writing benchmarks, and then building a jar application, and launching the application itself. I would like to know if it will be possible to use the power of `jmh` for use by analogy with unit tests, just like that part of the project that runs as a build task.

I use `gradle` for my kotlin projects. I expect to call benchmarks with a command like `gradle lib:runBenchmark`. The `me.champeau.jmh` plugin seems redundant to me, as there were legends ([for example](https://arbitrary-but-fixed.net/java/algorithms/2019/09/29/jmh-gradle-config.html)) that it is enough just to create a gradle task of the `JavaExec` type and run the `org.openjdk.jmh.Main` class passing certain parameters to it.

So far, I have managed to run benchmarks written in java in a similar way. But `jmh` stubbornly refuses to start seeing annotated classes written in kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

[org.openjdk.jmh](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.jmh) has tool [jmh-generator-bytecode](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-generator-bytecode). With it, you can create a task in `gradle` that generates the necessary code from sets (`kotlin` or `java` does not matter):

```
val outputSourceDir = File(buildDir, "jmhGenerated/sources")
val outputResourceDir = File(buildDir, "jmhGenerated/resources")
// Usage: generator <compiled-bytecode-dir> <output-source-dir> <output-resource-dir> [generator-type]
val generatorTask = task<JavaExec>("jmhRunBytecodeGenerator") {
    dependsOn("classes")
    mainClass.set("org.openjdk.jmh.generators.bytecode.JmhBytecodeGenerator")
    classpath = sourceSets["jmh"].runtimeClasspath
    args(
        compiledBytecodePath,
        outputSourceDir.absolutePath,
        outputResourceDir.absolutePath,
        "default"
    )
}
```

Then you can compile the code generated earlier:

```
val outputClassesDir = File(buildDir, "jmhGenerated/classes")
val compileTask = task<JavaCompile>("jmhCompileGenerated") {
    dependsOn(generatorTask)
    classpath = sourceSets["jmh"].runtimeClasspath
    source(outputSourceDir)
    destinationDirectory.set(outputClassesDir)
}
```

And in the end, run the benchmark with a task in which you can pass the paths to the compiled new classes:

```
task<JavaExec>("runBenchmark") {
    dependsOn(compileGeneratedTask)
    doFirst {
        File(buildDir, "reports/jmh").mkdirs()
    }
    mainClass.set("org.openjdk.jmh.Main")
    classpath(
        sourceSets["jmh"].runtimeClasspath,
        outputResourceDir,
        outputClassesDir
    )
    args(TODO())
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/kepocnhh/JMHSorting) you can see an example of how I use this method in my project.